How to calculate the flow of $(\phi_{t_0})_* X$?
$M$ is a smooth manifold. $X$ is a vector field. $\phi_t$ is the flow of $X$, namely
$$
\partial_t \phi_t (p) = X(\phi_t(p))
\tag{1}
$$
Now, for a fixed $t_0$, consider vector field $(\phi_{t_0})_* X$, where $(\phi_{t_0})_*$ is the tangent map induced by $\phi_{t_0}$, namely the differential of $\phi_{t_0}$.
This problem stems from another problem.
